# For any language L over ∑*, L* L*=L*

Tags: regex, concatenation, regular-language

Learning this for one of my classes

For every language L over ∑ * , L* L*=L*

Is this true or false?

I feel that it's false since because when you concatenate two languages the size of the elements is larger than either of the languages being concatenated. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: "when you concatenate two languages the size of the elements is larger than either of the languages being concatenated" - you're talking like all elements of a language have the same single size.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok, yes i see your point, you are right, i was thinking of an alphebet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not thinking about this the right way.  Your intuitions will lead you astray at first.  In this case, just because the formula is larger doesn't mean that the set is larger.

Let's suppose L = a.

So, what are the members of L*?  Λ, a, aa, aaa, etc.

What are the members of L*L*, which is equal to a*a*?  Λ, a, aa, aaa, etc.

You can see that in this case they are the same.  Can you think of any case where a member of L*L* is not also a member of L*?  (Hint: no.  why not?)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. This also helped me arrive at the answer:
Let w∈L∗L∗. This implies [...] and thus w∈L∗
Let w∈L∗. This implies [...] and thus w∈L∗L∗

Comment: Yup, that's a great way to construct the argument.